# EM algo returns different answers using pykalman

Tags: python, kalman-filter, state-space, expectation-maximization, pykalman

I came across a problem when I was using `pykalman 0.9.5` in `Python 3.6.3`

Refer to the code below, why are the results from `kf2` and `kf3` are different while the results from `kf1` and `kf3` are identical?

The difference of process between `kf2` and `kf3` is that I merely split the iteration into running 2 times of the function for `kf2`.

Thanks for everyone looking into it.

```
>>>pri_mean[:10]
array([ 2827.2222,  2829.6   ,  2831.    ,  2832.1   ,  2833.1   ,  2835.3   ,  2833.9   ,
        2833.8   ,  2833.6   ,  2833.    ])

>>>kf1 = KalmanFilter()
>>>kf1 = kf1.em(pri_mean, 10, em_vars='all')
>>>print(kf1.transition_matrices, kf1.transition_offsets, kf1.transition_covariance)
[[ 0.99741876]] [ 10.04426882] [[ 2896.92752373]]
>>>kf2 = kf1.em(pri_mean, 10, em_vars='all')
>>>print(kf2.transition_matrices, kf2.transition_offsets, kf2.transition_covariance)
[[ 0.99364606]] [ 20.02260806] [[ 2600.94151188]]

>>>kf3 = KalmanFilter()
>>>kf3 = kf3.em(pri_mean, 20, em_vars='all')
>>>print(kf3.transition_matrices, kf3.transition_offsets, kf3.transition_covariance)
[[ 0.99741876]] [ 10.04426882] [[ 2896.92752373]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the answer, since I misunderstood the question. I think the problem is that you are missing the keyword `n_iter`

See this code:

```
kf1 = KalmanFilter()
kf1 = kf1.em(pri_mean, n_iter=10, em_vars='all')
print(kf1.transition_matrices, kf1.transition_offsets, kf1.transition_covariance)
kf1 = kf1.em(pri_mean, n_iter=10, em_vars='all')
print(kf1.transition_matrices, kf1.transition_offsets, kf1.transition_covariance)
kf1 = KalmanFilter()
kf1 = kf1.em(pri_mean, n_iter=20, em_vars='all')
print(kf1.transition_matrices, kf1.transition_offsets, kf1.transition_covariance)
```

I create one filter through `KalmanFilter()`, loop 10 iterations and print, then 10 more and print.
This is equivalent as calling `.em()` with 20 iterations straight away.

Would produce the following output

```
[[ 0.95500561]] [ 113.29118228] [[ 6431.66262464]]
[[ 0.93636512]] [ 119.32378005] [[ 249.67547612]]
[[ 0.93636512]] [ 119.32378005] [[ 249.67547612]]
```

Comment: Hi drublackberry, thanks for your answer. I overwrote kf1 on purpose because I want to compare kf2, which just iterates 20 times in total just like kf3, and kf3 itself, which iterates 20 times in one function. Should the results between calling em(n_iter=10) two times and calling em(n_iter=20) one time being the same? I am confused.

Comment: Sorry @Gabriel_F I misunderstood. I edited the answer so now should work.

Comment: So it did! However, I still don't understand. Which part did I misunderstand? In my example, kf1 and k3 should not affect each other comparing to your first 'kf1' instance and second 'kf1' instance.

Comment: Simpler than that, you forgot to tell your call that 10 or 20 were `n_iter`. Your sequence of instantiation should work just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just tried it and got what I want like you said. Thanks a lot. What a stupid mistake.